# How do you determine the upper-left coordinates of a rectangle based on the center coordinates?

Tags: java, coordinates, rectangles

Based on the coordinate system, how would you determine the upper left coordinates of a rectangle if you are only given the center coordinates of the rectangle and the width and height?

For example, the center coordinates for a rectangle are (40,40) and the rectangle has a width of 90 and a height of 60.

Comment: This is really *a maths question*, not a programming question, but I'll refrain from voting to close it since it's so elementary.

Comment: Are you sure you have tried something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If center is `(x,y)`
width = `w`
height = `h`

Assuming the rectangle is sitting flat relative to the coordinate plane, the upper left corner is exactly (`x-w/2`, `y-h/2`).

Comment: How would you do the same thing but when the rectangle is e.g. rotated by 60 degrees clockwise?

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided corresponds to the BOTTOM LEFT corner...
For UPPER LEFT corner in a xy coordinate system would be (x-w/2, y+h/2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).